# UIColor conversion from RGB to HSV , set brightness to UIColor

Tags: xcode4, ios5, uicolor

In my app I am trying to draw with different colors. I have my own color picker, but I want to add to this picker slider for color brightness. For understudying : I choose a color which is displayed somewhere in view as background color and to this color I want add slider which will slide from 1 to 0 and change brightness of the color and displays the color in window.  Therefore I want to ask if there is any possible way how to convert.

in my project I use this :

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(current, R, G, B, A);
```

so anytime I slide the slider I need to change the brightness of the color, therefore I need to convert my `UIColor` - represented as RGB to HSV and than back to RGB for using it one more time.

Does exist any RGB to HSV conversion algorithm or is there any in iOS 5 or Xcode4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```c
+(struct hsv_color)HSVfromRGB:(struct rgb_color)rgb
{
    struct hsv_color hsv;

    CGFloat rgb_min, rgb_max;
    rgb_min = MIN3(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
    rgb_max = MAX3(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);

    if (rgb_max == rgb_min) {
        hsv.hue = 0;
    } else if (rgb_max == rgb.r) {
        hsv.hue = 60.0f * ((rgb.g - rgb.b) / (rgb_max - rgb_min));
        hsv.hue = fmodf(hsv.hue, 360.0f);
    } else if (rgb_max == rgb.g) {
        hsv.hue = 60.0f * ((rgb.b - rgb.r) / (rgb_max - rgb_min)) + 120.0f;
    } else if (rgb_max == rgb.b) {
        hsv.hue = 60.0f * ((rgb.r - rgb.g) / (rgb_max - rgb_min)) + 240.0f;
    }
    hsv.val = rgb_max;
    if (rgb_max == 0) {
        hsv.sat = 0;
    } else {
        hsv.sat = 1.0 - (rgb_min / rgb_max);
    }

    return hsv;
}
```

Comment: Sure here is a link:
http://code.google.com/p/iphone-color-picker/source/browse/trunk/Classes/UIColor-HSVAdditions.m?r=6

Comment: There's one small "bug". Assuming you want hue to be non-negative, change the `hsv.hue = fmodf(hsv.hue, 360.0f);` line to `hsv.hue = fmodf(hsv.hue + 360.0f, 360.0f);`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if in your original question you really want "brightness" or alpha. RGB and HSV color schemes are completely different.

If I interpret your intent correctly:

**You do not need to convert from RGB to HSV and back to RGB if all you want to do is control the alpha channel for an RGB color.**

The simplest and most efficient way to achieve what you want to do is to simply add a slider for alpha and take the output from that to change color transparency.